# How to put user input into an array? Can for statements go inside an if/else statement? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, prompt

I understand this may contain completely inane methods, but I am just playing around here to learn.
My question is whether or not one can use an if statement inside an if/else statement like I have done.
Lastly, how would you go about prompting for input and putting it into an array?

```
var inputArr1 = prompt('Type a noun');
var inputArr2 = prompt('Type another noun');
var inputArr3 = prompt('Type another noun');
var inputArr4 = prompt('Type a final noun');

document.getElementById("inputArr1").value;
document.getElementById("inputArr2").value;
document.getElementById("inputArr3").value;
document.getElementById("inputArr4").value;

var recordedArray = [ inputArr1, inputArr2, inputArr3, inputArr4 ];

if (recordedArray.length == 3){
    for (var i = 0; i <= recordedArray.length; i++){
         console.log("I like to eat " + recordedArray[i] + " with ketchup!");
}
else {
    console.log("You did not type a proper entry or something. Try again.");
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can, but you misnested your braces.

Comment: Yep, I totally see that now. 
Now how about the other question, any suggestions on how to prompt for input and put it into an array?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Prompting user and saving responses to an array can be done like this:

```
var questions = [ "question1", "question2", "question3" ];
var answers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  answers.push(prompt(questions[i]));
}
console.log(answers);
```

It looks like you have something wrong with braces around if-else statement (everything is in *if* and *else* refers to *for* loop), but the idea was good.
Moreover you need to know that your recordedArray length will be equal to 4, not 3.

Furthermore the code below does nothing or generates errors:

```
document.getElementById("inputArr1").value;
document.getElementById("inputArr2").value;
document.getElementById("inputArr3").value;
document.getElementById("inputArr4").value;
```

document.getElementById() looks for HTML element, if it does not exist you will get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

so i recommend to remove these lines of code.

Comment: Any explanations? Just a snippet of code and what then?

Comment: What do you think needs an explanation?

Comment: I like your solution, Daniel. 
When the .length command occurs, doesn't it start counting at 0 so the length would be 3?
(What term does one use to refer to a ".length" or ".push"?)

Comment: The last element index is array length - 1. Indexes are 0-3, so length is 4. Length is a field and push() is a method of class Array. You can find out more details here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Answer (score -2):

Put all your prompts into an array

```
    var prompts[4]="p1...","p2...","p3...","p4...";

    foreach item in prompts
        {
        console.log("before text"+item+"after text");
        }
```